# Screenshot size limitations changing google play

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upload screenshots to google play and have them all to the same dimensions.  Some of them have a bigger file size by .3 mb.

My problem is that every time i try to upload a second screen shot it always says its too big.(max 3mb)

I tried deleting the first screen shot and then adding the second one but still says its too big.

I then change the file size to half of what it was, then it changes again to a max of 576kb

What am i doing wrong? should my screenshots be different dimensions? and if so will they still show up the same size in the google play store

Answer (score 0):

If your screenshot is bigger than 3MB you probably have a very inefficient encoding, or your tool you are using to make the screenshot is adding a lot of metadata. The [support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en&ref_topic=2897459) says:

- JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)
- Minimum dimension: 320px
- Maximum dimension: 3840px
- The maximum dimension of your screenshot can't be more than twice as long as the minimum dimension.

If you are sticking to these guidelines it is unlikely your screenshot will be more than 3MB. If it is, you could try using a JPEG optimizer / shrinker tool. There seem to be lots available, (eg [this one](https://tinyjpg.com/) but I haven't tried it)